# How to convert PDF to clean HTML using Python

Tags: python, html, pdf, flask, pdfminer

I want to have the user upload a PDF, convert that PDF to HTML code and insert this code into a `<div>` to display the PDF document. I'm using PDFMiner to analyze the uploaded PDF. When I convert it to HTML, the HTML is messy and the document is wrongly displayed [HTML Mess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An3mr.png)
. I've tried XML, but it's still unusable because the text gets displayed with no spaces. How can I improve this? Thank you.

```
def main():

 contentRaw =  convert_pdf(file.filename, 'html')
 contentR = json.dumps(contentRaw)
 contentOut = (contentRaw)
 return render_template('app.html', title=" App", filename=file.filename, content=Markup(contentOut), instructions=instructions)



def convert_pdf(path, format='text', codec='utf-8', password=''):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = BytesIO()
    laparams = LAParams()
    if format == 'text':
        device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    elif format == 'html':
        device = HTMLConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    elif format == 'xml':
        device = XMLConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    else:
        raise ValueError('provide format, either text, html or xml!')
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue().decode()
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text
```

Comment: Instead of converting to HTML, PDFs should be displayed using a library such as PDF.js: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: @MaxiMouse I want to display the pdf inside an other element of my page like a div. Can PDF.js help with this? Also, I think PDF.js runs on the webserver and I'm using python for this project. Is there any library similar to pdf.js written in Python? I haven't found anything reliable.

Comment: PDF.js runs in the browser. It renders the PDF onto a `canvas` element, which you can put into a div.

Answer (score 0):

PDF is a very reach format, it is not a markup language only (HTML is).

Writing a PDF to HTML convertor, which preserves a document look, is quite a complex story: your software must understand all commands, objects, maintain graphics state etc. Do all the things that a conforming PDF reader and viewer does. 
And after all convert document content to HTML.

You can start from [PDF 1.7 specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

I'd suggest you to have a look at [pdfreader](https://pdfreader.readthedocs.io/) and code a custom PDFViewer or deal somehow with text + pdf commands it can extract.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using an existing PDF to HTML converter? An example using an existing library:

```
import pdftables_api

c = pdftables_api.Client('my-api-key')
c.html('input.pdf', 'output.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested to try some other Python package then I would suggest [Aspose.Words Cloud SDK for Python](https://docs.aspose.cloud/words/convert/specified-format/). It honors the formatting in PDF to HTML conversion.

```
# For complete examples and data files, please go to https://github.com/aspose-words-cloud/aspose-words-cloud-python
# Import module
import asposewordscloud
import asposewordscloud.models.requests
from shutil import copyfile

# Please get your Client ID and Secret from https://dashboard.aspose.cloud.
client_id='xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx'
client_secret='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

words_api = asposewordscloud.WordsApi(client_id,client_secret)
words_api.api_client.configuration.host='https://api.aspose.cloud'

filename = 'C:/Temp/02_pages.pdf'
dest_name = 'C:/Temp/02_pages.html'
#Convert RTF to text
request = asposewordscloud.models.requests.ConvertDocumentRequest(document=open(filename, 'rb'), format='html')
result = words_api.convert_document(request)
copyfile(result, dest_name)
```

P.S: I'm developer evangelist at Aspose